# How to manipulate a FQDN variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dns, python-3.7

I have some functional code that is doing what I want. It takes a DNS response, breaks the response into all of its parts (i.e. hostname, all optional sub domain names, domain name, and tld), and then strips the hostname and trailing dot off of the entire DNS response and displays the entire domain (with optional subdomains)

Please note that the variable for "FQDN" will be a dynamic DNS response and/or user input.

How could I setup the code to function regardless if there is a trailing dot on hte variable or not (i.e. function for "hostname.domain.com" and also for "hostname.domain.com.")?

I am also curious if anyone has any suggestions on how to improve this code overall while producing the same output. Thanks in advance!

```
fqdn = "computername.subdomainname1.subdomainname2.domainname.com."

dot, tld, domain, *sub_domains, hostname = fqdn.split(".")[::-1]

testname = fqdn.split(hostname + ".")

before = len("")
after = len(".")
parsed_testname = (testname[1][before:-after])

print(hostname)
print(parsed_testname)
```

The output is:

```
computername
subdomainname1.subdomainname2.domainname.com
```

Comment: Couple questions: 

1) do you need to keep track of `tld`, `domain`, `sub_domains`, etc., or is that just extra? 
2) should your output retain the trailing `.` if there is one?

Comment: Do you expect `before = len("") ; after = len(".")` to *ever* be anything *other* than `0` and `1`?

Comment: If you need to "nornalize" names, note that you have a lot of other stuff to do besides the trailing dot. Case is one for example (hostnames are case insensitive, and you can get replies with mixed cases), and if user input is restricted you might get non ASCII characters, and for hostnames you need to apply IDNA on them to go back to ASCII. PS: please use `example.com` or `.example` TLD when you need to use fake names.

Comment: @Chance - I do need to keep track of sub_domains (if they exist) separately and domain... however, the tld can (or not) be combined with the domain variable. (for example... it could be "domain.com" or "domain" and "com" either way.

Comment: @DeepSpace - That piece of code is literally just a hack to make the script do what I wanted. It's only purpose was to strip off the trailing "."

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - Correct on all counts. I should have clarified in my original question that those edge cases are handled on a downstream api. Thanks for the tip on example.com & .example - I will do so in the future. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

You could always call `.rstrip(".")` on the input!

```py
>>> "foo".rstrip(".")
'foo'
>>> "foo.".rstrip(".")
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way to get hostname:

```
fqdn = "computername.subdomainname1.subdomainname2.domainname.com."
pieces = fqdn.split(".")
hostname = pieces[0]
testname = '.'.join(pieces[1:])
print(hostname)
print(testname)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to always call `.rstrip('.')` on the input, it appears that all you want to achieve is a separation between whatever is before the first `.` and all the rest.

You can just use `.split` with `maxsplit=1`:

```
delimiter = '.'
hostname, parsed_testname = fqdn.rstrip(delimiter).split(delimiter, maxsplit=1)
```